How to create a curved cylinder in TikZ with a custom base shape?
I’m trying to create a curved cylinder in TikZ with a specific base shape. Here is the base shape I want to use:

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

% PARALLEL AXIS
\def\L{1.2}    % size scale
\def\d{2.2}    % distance parallel axis to M
\def\ang{-20}  % angle connection between axes
\def\bodyshape{
  (-100:1.0*\L) to[out=190,in=-90]
  (180:1.4*\L) to[out=90,in=175]
  (110:1.0*\L) to[out=-5,in=185]
  ($(R)+(110:0.6*\L)$) to[out=5,in=90]
  ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$) to[out=-90,in=-20]
  ($(R)+(-120:0.7*\L)$) to[out=160,in=10] cycle
}
\def\body{ % shape
  \fill[ball color=red!80!black] \bodyshape;
  \draw[line width=0.6,draw=red!30!black,fill=red!60!black!5,fill opacity=0.85]
    \bodyshape;
  %\fill[mass] \bodyshape;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
          \coordinate (M) at (0,0); % center of mass
          \coordinate (R) at (\ang:\d); % intersection with new axis
          \body
          \node at (M) {M}; % center of mass point replaced with "M"
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


I want to use this base shape to create a curved cylinder. How can I achieve this in TikZ?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Here is an illustration of the base shape I want to use:

After applying suggestion of @dexteritas and   adding an extra scope to capture the hidden edge of the object, I obtained the following picture: but it’s not perfect. I’m trying to adjust the dashed line to represent the hidden edge.
To further illustrate my goal, here is a sketch that demonstrates what I am aiming to achieve:
I hope these images clarify my intent.
Update:
Thanks to the suggestion from @dexteritas, I was able to achieve my aims as follows:
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% PARALLEL AXIS
    \def\L{0.3}    % size scale
    \def\A{0.45}    % height axis above body
    \def\d{0.55}    % distance parallel axis to M
    \def\ang{-20}  % angle connection between axes
    \def\bodyshape{
      (-100:1.0*\L) to[out=190,in=-90]
      (180:1.4*\L) to[out=90,in=175]
      (110:1.0*\L) to[out=-5,in=185]
      ($(R)+(110:0.6*\L)$) to[out=5,in=90]
      ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$) to[out=-90,in=-20]
      ($(R)+(-120:0.7*\L)$) to[out=160,in=10] cycle
    }
    \def\body{ % shape
      \fill[ball color=red!80!black] \bodyshape;
      \draw[line width=0.6,draw=red!30!black,fill=red!60!black!5,fill opacity=0.85]
        \bodyshape;
    }
    
    \def\initMR{
      \coordinate (M) at (0,0); % center of mass
      \coordinate (R) at ($(M) + (\ang:\d)$); % intersection with new axis
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
    myline/.style={line width=0.6, draw=red!30!black}
]
     \begin{scope}[yshift=-0.5cm] % Shift the first figure down
        \initMR
        \body
        \node[scale=0.5] at (M) {M}; % center of mass point replaced with "M", resized
      \end{scope}
    
      \begin{scope}[xshift=1.75cm] % Shift the second figure to the right
        \def\height{5mm}
        
        % draw lower half of the second shape
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-\height]
            \initMR
            \draw [myline, fill=red!10]
                ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L) + (0,\height)$) --
                ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$) to[out=-90,in=-20]
                ($(R)+(-120:0.7*\L)$) to[out=160,in=10]
                (-100:1.0*\L) to[out=190,in=-90]
                (180:1.4*\L)
                -- ++(0,\height);
        \end{scope}
        
        % draw shape
        \initMR
        \fill[ball color=red!80!black] \bodyshape;
        \draw[myline, fill=red!60!black!5, fill opacity=0.85] \bodyshape;
        \node[scale=0.5] at  ($(M)+(.075,-.5)$) {M$\times$I}; % center of mass point replaced with "MI", resized
        
        % draw dashed line (upper half of shape)
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-\height]
            \initMR
            \draw [myline, dashed, dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt]
                (180:1.4*\L) to[out=90,in=175]
                (110:1.0*\L) to[out=-5,in=185]
                ($(R)+(110:0.6*\L)$) to[out=5,in=90]
                ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$);
        \end{scope}
          % Add arrows between the figures
          \draw[-latex] (-0.95,-0.7) -- node[midway,above] {$i_0$} (-0.4,-0.7); % Arrow with label i_0 at 0 degrees
          \draw[-latex] (-1.1,-0.5) -- node[midway,above] {$i_1$} (-0.45,0.05); % Arrow with label i_1 at calculated angle
         
      \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result:


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to make it compilable? It should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}

Please test your code before uploading it. There are several problems.

Sorry, I thought it was clear for everyone. I have added that to the code.  I hope this makes it clearer.

Sorry @hpekristiansen, it was because I forgot to include \usetikzlibrary{calc} in the code. I've added it now.

New Version (with dashed line)
Adaptations

added a parameter height
draw the lower half of the shape plus two vertical lines again within a scope, with [yshift=-\height]

(It would also be possible to redraw the whole shape again within the scope and add the two vertical lines.)


added class option border=3mm
removed duplicate \def\body

Adaptations for new version

added a second scope for drawing the dashed upper half of the shape below
defined tikz style myline
defined \initMR
moved content \body directly into the tikzpicture environment as it was only used once
removed unused variables \A and \anga

Code
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% PARALLEL AXIS
\def\L{1.2}    % size scale
\def\d{2.2}    % distance parallel axis to M
\def\ang{-20}  % angle connection between axes
\def\initMR{
    \coordinate (M) at (0,0); % center of mass
    \coordinate (R) at ($(M) + (\ang:\d)$); % intersection with new axis
}
\def\bodyshape{
    (-100:1.0*\L) to[out=190,in=-90]
    (180:1.4*\L) to[out=90,in=175]
    (110:1.0*\L) to[out=-5,in=185]
    ($(R)+(110:0.6*\L)$) to[out=5,in=90]
    ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$) to[out=-90,in=-20]
    ($(R)+(-120:0.7*\L)$) to[out=160,in=10] cycle
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    myline/.style={line width=0.6, draw=red!30!black}
]
    \def\height{6mm}
    
    % draw lower half of shape
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-\height]
        \initMR
        \draw [myline, fill=red!10]
            ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L) + (0,\height)$) --
            ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$) to[out=-90,in=-20]
            ($(R)+(-120:0.7*\L)$) to[out=160,in=10]
            (-100:1.0*\L) to[out=190,in=-90]
            (180:1.4*\L)
            -- ++(0,\height);
    \end{scope}
    
    % draw shape
    \initMR
    \fill[ball color=red!80!black] \bodyshape;
    \draw[myline, fill=red!60!black!5, fill opacity=0.85] \bodyshape;
    \node at (M) {M}; % center of mass point replaced with "M"
    
    % draw dashed line (upper half of shape)
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-\height]
        \initMR
        \draw [myline, dashed, dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt]
            (180:1.4*\L) to[out=90,in=175]
            (110:1.0*\L) to[out=-5,in=185]
            ($(R)+(110:0.6*\L)$) to[out=5,in=90]
            ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result

Old Version
Code
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% PARALLEL AXIS
\def\L{1.2}    % size scale
\def\A{1.8}    % height axis above body
\def\d{2.2}    % distance parallel axis to M
\def\ang{-20}  % angle connection between axes
\def\anga{72}  % angle axes
\def\bodyshape{
    (-100:1.0*\L) to[out=190,in=-90]
    (180:1.4*\L) to[out=90,in=175]
    (110:1.0*\L) to[out=-5,in=185]
    ($(R)+(110:0.6*\L)$) to[out=5,in=90]
    ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$) to[out=-90,in=-20]
    ($(R)+(-120:0.7*\L)$) to[out=160,in=10] cycle
}
\def\body{ % shape
    \coordinate (M) at (0,0); % center of mass
    \coordinate (R) at ($(M) + (\ang:\d)$); % intersection with new axis
    \fill[ball color=red!80!black] \bodyshape;
    \draw[line width=0.6, draw=red!30!black, fill=red!60!black!5, fill opacity=0.85] \bodyshape;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\height{6mm}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-\height]
        \coordinate (M) at (0,0); % center of mass
        \coordinate (R) at ($(M) + (\ang:\d)$); % intersection with new axis
        \draw [line width=0.6, draw=red!30!black, fill=red!10]
            ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L) + (0,\height)$) --
            ($(R)+(15:0.7*\L)$) to[out=-90,in=-20]
            ($(R)+(-120:0.7*\L)$) to[out=160,in=10]
            (-100:1.0*\L) to[out=190,in=-90]
            (180:1.4*\L)
            -- ++(0,\height);
            cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \body
    \node at (M) {M}; % center of mass point replaced with "M"
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result


Thank you for your answer. However, the hidden edge of the bottom base of the cylinder was not visible in your solution. I tried to achieve it using a new scope with symmetric coordinates regarding the last one, but the result is not perfect. \node at ($(M)+(0.1,0.1)$) {M};\begin{scope}[yshift=-\height] \coordinate (M) at (0,0);\coordinate (R) at ($(M) + (\ang:\d)$);\draw [dashed, dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt, line width=0.6, draw=red!30!black] ($(R)-(-120:0.7*\L)$) to[out=-170,in=-10, looseness=1](100:1.0*\L) to[out=10,in=90, looseness=1 (-180:1.4*\L) -- ++(0,\height);cycle;\end{scope}

Ok, since you did not mention in your question what the 3D representation should look like, I decided to use a solid body. Of course it can be adjusted. But for your next question, be sure to describe your desired result in more detail, or make a sketch of it as an image if necessary.

Thank you for your guidance. I understand the importance of providing a clear description or visual representation of my desired outcome. I have attached two images: the first one demonstrates my attempt to capture the hidden edge which is not perfect, and the last one illustrates my goal.

@mori I added a new version with a dashed line and some other improvements to my answer.

Based on this post by a missing old contributor @Marmot, an implementation that accommodates 3D transformations that allows using tikz-3dplot, then, to recreate the volume I had nothing left but to iterate shadows and mix them using the opacity, change the type path that you defined since I need 2 points where to draw the projection of the limit of the figures and this is found using the pos parameter that works in controls, but not in to[in= ,out=], so I defined the path again but using 4 variables, 1 for the R coordinate, the second for the ID of the points, the third and fourth to modify the position of the points l and k, which will draw the limit of the volume, see how this parameter varied in both green and red figures.
I'm sorry if the code is obscure but I also don't have much experience in 3D things, but I achieved this by testing things and finding out what happens as always. Note that the green object is in rotation transformation coordinates.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{105}{-30}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        tdplot_main_coords,
        font=\sffamily
        ]
        % PARALLEL AXIS
        \def\L{1.2}    % size scale
        \def\A{1.8}    % height axis above body
        \def\d{2.2}    % distance parallel axis to M
        \def\ang{-20}  % angle connection between axes
        \def\anga{72}  % angle axes
        \def\Mypath#1#2#3#4{
            (-100:1.0*\L)
                .. controls +(190:1) and +(-90:1) .. (180:1.4*\L)
                .. controls +(90:0.6) and +(175:0.6) .. (110:1.0*\L)node[pos=#3](k-#2){}
                .. controls +(5:0.6) and +(185:0.6) .. ($(#1)+(110:0.6*\L)$)%to[out=-5,in=185]
                .. controls +(5:0.5) and +(90:0.5) .. ($(#1)+(15:0.7*\L)$)%to[out=5,in=90] 
                .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-20:0.5) .. ($(#1)+(-120:0.7*\L)$)node[pos=#4](l-#2){}
                .. controls +(160:0.5) and +(10:0.5) .. cycle %to [out=160,in=10]
        }
        \coordinate (R) at (\ang:\d); % intersection with new axis
        
        %RED SHAPE
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
            \draw[fill=red!50!black,fill opacity=0.5]\Mypath{\ang:\d}{a}{0.25}{0.22};
        \end{scope} 
    
        \begin{scope}[shift={(1,0)},canvas is xy plane at z=\A,transform shape]
            \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.2]\Mypath{\ang:\d}{b}{0.25}{0.22};
        \end{scope}
    
        \draw(k-a.center).. controls +(0,0,1) and +(0,0,-1) ..(k-b.center);
        \draw(l-a.center).. controls +(0,0,1) and +(0,0,-1) ..(l-b.center);
        
        \foreach \j in {1,...,50}{
            \path(0,0,0).. controls +(0,0,1) and +(0,0,-1) ..(1,0,\A) node[pos=1/50*\j](m){};
            \begin{scope}[shift={(m.center)},canvas is xy plane at z=0, transform shape,transparency group]
                \fill[fill=red!\j!red!50!black,opacity=0.07]\Mypath{\ang:\d}{b}{0.25}{0.22};
            \end{scope} 
        }
        %GREEN SHAPE
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{210}
        \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(-5,0,0)},canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
                \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5]\Mypath{\ang:\d}{a}{0.6}{0.6};
            \end{scope} 
            
            \begin{scope}[shift={(-5,0,0)},,canvas is xy plane at z=\A,transform shape]
                \path[fill=green!50!black,fill opacity=0.5]\Mypath{\ang:\d}{b}{0.6}{0.6};
            \end{scope}
            
            \draw(k-a.center).. controls +(0,0,1) and +(0,0,-1) ..(k-b.center);
            \draw(l-a.center).. controls +(0,0,1) and +(0,0,-1) ..(l-b.center);
            
            \foreach \j in {1,...,50}{
                \path(-5,0,0) -- (-5,0,\A) node[pos=1/50*\j](n){};
                \begin{scope}[shift={(n.center)},canvas is xy plane at z=0, transform shape,transparency group]
                    \fill[fill=green!\j!green!50!black,opacity=0.07]\Mypath{\ang:\d}{b}{0}{0};
                \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[shift={(-5,0,0)},,canvas is xy plane at z=\A,transform shape]
                \draw[draw opacity=0.8]\Mypath{\ang:\d}{b}{0.6}{0.6};
            \end{scope}
            }
        \end{scope}
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{1.5}
        \draw[-stealth]  (0,0,0)-- (2.5*\Radius,0,0) node[pos=1.15] {$x$};
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,3.5*\Radius,0) node[pos=1.15] {$y$};
        \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2.5*\Radius) node[pos=1.05] {$z$};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document} 

